# Is there any way to identify the class (in a hierarchy) from which you called a static method?

Tags: java, class, methods, static

Let's say we have:

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(A.getCallerClass()) // Should print "A"
        System.out.print(B.getCallerClass()) // Should print "B"
        System.out.print(C.getCallerClass()) // Should print "C"
    }
}
class A
{
    public static String getCallerClassName()
    {
        // Not sure how to define the method body
    }
}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}
```

As you can see, I want `getCallerClassName()` to only be defined in `A` and return the simple name of the class responsible for initially calling it. I have tried methods such as calling `MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass()` and looking at the stack trace to no avail.

Comment: There is not a reliable way to do this. Please explain why you want to; there is likely another approach to doing it.

Comment: That smells like an antipattern.  A method should provide a service, not do different things depending on who called it.  If there are legitimate reasons for doing different things, provide different methods, or add a method argument saying what is to be done.

Comment: @chrylis -cautioslyoptimistic- I want to get a class-dependent return value from a static method because I have a static hash map in a super class from which I want to access different values dependent on the subclass. Essentially, through an accessor method, I want to use the name of the calling subclass as a key for the hash map. I know this is complicated, but this is an approach I thought of since I want to be the most compatible when adding additional subclasses.

Comment: Static map sounds questionable. What are you _actually trying to accomplish_? What are these "different values"? How do they vary with the subclass? How do the callers decide what specific class to use as a key?

Comment: I have a `Point` abstract class and multiple subclasses (`Point#`). For each `Point#` class I have, I want to have a corresponding origin point (`Point1 -> (0)`, `Point2 -> (0, 0)`, etc...). So, instead of having an origin static field for each and every `Point#`, I thought I could have a one data structure stored in one static field in the `Point` class that, through an accessor method, accepts the calling class's name as a key and returns as a value the class's corresponding origin.

Comment: The method body is simply `return "A";`; then define methods in B and C which do similarly, hiding the method in A.

Comment: Sorry, I meant with only defining the method in class `A`